# ReferenceError mongodb MapReduce

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I've got collection in mongodb called people. Below one of documents:

```
{
        id: 102
        sex: "Male"
        weight: "70.4"
        height: "180.3"

},
```

I wrote MapReduce which calculates avg weight and avg height per sex

```
var mapFunction= function(){
    var key=this.sex;
    var value= {
        count: 1,
        height: Number(this.height),
        weight: Number(this.number)
    };
    emit(key,value);
};  
var reduceFunction= function (key, values) {
    reducedVal= { count: 0, height: 0, weight: 0};
    for (var i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
        reducedVal.count +=value[i].count;
        reducedVal.height+=value[i].height;
        reducedVal.weight+=value[i].weight;
    }
    return reducedVal;

};
var finalizeFunction = function (key, reducedVal) {
    reducedVal.avg1= reducedVal.height/reducedVal.count;
    reducedVal.avg2= reducedVal.weight/reducedVal.count;
    return reducedVal;
};
db.people.mapReduce( mapFunction,
                     reduceFunction,
                     {
                       out: "map_reduce_example" ,
                       finalize: finalizeFunction
                     }
                   )
```

I received error when I tried to execute code. How can I fix it?

```
Error: map reduce failed:{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "ReferenceError: value is not defined :\n@:4:3\n",
    "code" : 139,
    "codeName" : "JSInterpreterFailure"

}
```

Comment: you have a typo, change `value` to `values` in `reduceFunction` inside for loop.

Comment: Thanks. I executed code. Height is working well but sum of weight is NaN. Do you know the reason?

Comment: Most probably, some of documents do not contain valid `weight` values. So add a check in reducefunction for loop. `if(!isNaN(values[i].height)) reducedVal.height+=value[i].height;` and `if(!isNaN(values[i].weight)) reducedVal.weight+=values[i].weight;`